# How do I change the old-style numerals in the Georgia font?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am planning to use Georgia Font in Xelatex for a formal report.

The font looks great except the numbers appears *informal* to me.

[image]

Informal here is some numbers like 4, and 5 are below the line. How can I fix this ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures for understanding of the "informal" appaerance of the numbers.

Comment: Note that most people will consider lining figures in running text to be **more** informal than text figures. Many common fonts still default to lining figures, which means only properly, often professionally, typeset text uses text figures. What everyone uses by default in their Word documents is of course the informal variety; what you see in professionally typeset books is considered more formal. I would advise against ‘fixing’ this, because it doesn’t need fixing – at least not in running text. Tables and titles are a different matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try lining numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}[Numbers=Lining]
\begin{document}
12345
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem.